# find a variable of struct from another index

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

In the bestGrade function I need to find the name of the student, not the index of the highest score or the score itself. How do I do that?

This is a separate issue I dont know how to get the txt file in the project with Xcode. I dont like xcode, but I can't install visual studio even after trying VirtualBox, Wine Botttler, and I had VM fusionware but I updated my iOS and now it wont work. So Im making lemonade.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <istream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;


void getData(ifstream& infile, studentType students[]);
void getGrade(ifstream& infile, studentType students[]);
void bestGrade(ofstream& outfile, studentType students[]);
void printStudents(ofstream& outfile, studentType students[]);

struct studentType
{
    string studentFName;
    string studentLName;
    int testScore;
    char grade;
};

studentType students[20];

int main()
{
    ifstream infile;
    ofstream outfile;


    infile.open("studentData.txt");
    outfile.open("studentDataOut.txt");



    infile.close();
    outfile.close();
}

void getData(ifstream& infile, studentType students[])//function to get data from text file
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        infile >> students[i].studentFName >> students[i].studentLName>>students[i].testScore;

}

void getGrade(ifstream& infile, studentType students[])//function to get grade based off test score
{
    int testScore;
    string studentFName;
    string studentLName;


    infile >> studentFName >> studentLName;

    while (infile)
    {
        infile >> testScore;
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            if(testScore>= 90)
                students[i].grade = 'A';
            else if(testScore >= 80)
                students[i].grade = 'B';
            else if(testScore >= 70)
                students[i].grade = 'C';
            else if (testScore >= 60)
                students[i].grade = 'D';
            else
                students[i].grade = 'F';
            }
            infile >> studentFName >> studentLName;
        }
}
void bestGrade(ofstream& outfile, studentType students[])//function to find best test score
{
    int bestgrade = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        if(students[i].testScore <= i)
            bestgrade = i;

}

void printStudents(ofstream& outfile, studentType students[])//function to output data
{
    outfile << "----- Student Name ----- Test Score ----- Grade" << endl;
    outfile<< endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        outfile << students[i].studentLName << ", " << students[i].studentFName
        << setw(5)<<students[i].testScore << setw(5)<<students[i].grade<< endl;
    outfile << endl;
}
```

Comment: You have to declare `studentType` **before** the function declarations.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare studentType before the function prototypes.

Answer (score 0):

1. for a type to be recognized, it should be declared "before/above" where it needs to be recognized. either move your studentType struct above your function prototypes, or forward-declare it like: `struct studentType;`
2. add this line:

   ```
   string bestStudentName = students[i].studentFName;
   ```